# Interpret <P> as <P.SERIF> in all paragraphs of a .Html file

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a CSS file that defines a class of paragraph, it's named `p.serif`.
I have an HTML file that depends on that CSS. For a single paragraph I can set `<p class="serif">`, and it works perfectly. But I want ALL my 400 paragraphs in the html to look as defined in p.serif without changing `<p>` to `<p class="serif">` 400 times. Of course, I can paste P.Class's characteristics into the head of the html as `<style>`, but I have many htmls like that, and I simply want to tell every html: 'P here is as defined in `p.serif`, apply the Serif class to **every** `<p>` you see in this html'. How could that be done, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a CSS rule for the `p` tag itself that has the same settings as your `.serif` class. For example:

```
p {
  font-family: /* whatever css settings .serif class contains */;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in this very example the browser would just apply its own default serif font to my paragraphs. It won't retrieve all my definitions I wrote in p.serif

Comment: As I wrote: Just use the settings that are in your `.serif` class in the rule for `p`. If there's a font-familiy setting with a particular font in there, copy it into the `p` rule, as well as all other settings.

Comment: This would have been an excellent option if my Serif class was stable and never changed. But tomorrow I decide to change the look of my Serif class — and should I then redo the pasting job again and again... I have 200+ htmls. I'd accept to add ONCE to each of them a command like "P here is as described in P.SERIF in CSS, go to CSS and apply". But repeating pasting of a modified Serif style every time I change it?.. Would be hard to do, I'm afraid. I wish to make the link dynamic, not absolute.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "200+ htmls" - if those are different pages of one website, there should be a common stylesheet, and if you change (or add) the rule for the `p` tag in there, that should be sufficient for all pages (?)

Comment: Thank you Johannes. I see your point, it's perfectly valid if only I had one <P> style to be applied to all my htmls. 
But the problem is that I have, e.g., 
50.html whose <P>s need to look as described in P.Serif, 
then 60.html whose <P>s need to look as described in P.Fantasy, 
then 99.html whose <P>s need to look as described in P.Holiday, etc.  
I want to be able to modify P.Serif in CSS and see those changes applied to my 50.html and other htmls similar to 50.html, but NOT to 60.html that should remain Fantasy or 99.html that should remain Holiday.

Comment: In this case I would apply different classes to the `body` elements of those html documents and then create a CSS rule like `.document1 p { ... }` Into which you copy (once) the settings of your `.serif` class. Then all `p`s which are a child element of `body.document1` will be affected. And different body classes for the other classes in other HTML documents.

Comment: Yes, indeed, this could work, I think. I never did this kind of things, but it's a challenge for me. Thank you very much Johannes!

Answer (score 0):

HTML has no mechanisms for applying adding a class to an element without actually changing the class attribute on each element you want to change.

You *could* write some JS to loop over all the paragraphs and modify their class lists, but your approach of adding the `style` element would be more efficient (and wouldn't break if additional paragraphs were dynamically added to the document).

Comment: Yes, the <Style> solution is good, but only if I have, say, 10 htmls to paste my P.serif's attributes from the CSS. I am supposed to modify from time to time my p.serif, and I have 200 htmls. if I do the copy-paste 200 times ONCE, it's fine, but if I have to paste the modified css EVERY time, it's a headache :-(